# How to dump info to excel from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, excel

I'm receiving some JSON data from a get request and I need to format this data into a table and then write it to an excel sheet. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What back-end technology do you use for your project? It's recommended to be done on the server side.

Comment: C# Web API. A rest API where I call controllers for my data. It needs to be done client side because I don't want to be storing a bunch of excel sheets on the server.

Comment: ExcellentExport may do what you want: http://jordiburgos.com/post/2014/excellentexport-javascript-export-to-excel-csv.html

Answer (score 0):

How about a tab separated csv file?

```
function makeCsv(table) {
  var contents = [];
  table.forEach(function(row) {
    contents.push('"'+row.join('";"')+'"');
  });
  return new Blob(contents, { type: 'text/csv' });
}

window.location = URL.createObjectURL(makeCsv([[1, 2],[3, 4]]));
```

you could use HTML5 saveAs, see [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)